# How can I make a DIY macro lens for a smartphone?

Tags: lens, macro, smartphone

I'm a new photographer. I like macro photography so much, but I can't buy a DSLR right now. So I'm doing photography using my smart phone. I bought a macro lens for smart phones from eBay but its magnification is low.

1. Is there any way to improve my lens?
2. Can I make a DIY lens for smart phones?

Comment: You can buy add-on macro lenses for many phones (semi-universal). They're not great but they're not as bad as you'd think. Quite good for playing with macro photography.

Comment: That's right. I've done some cool macros using that lens

Comment: I've got [this one ](http://m.iwantoneofthose.com/gift-tech-stuff/snap-macro-lens-for-phone-cameras/10844069.html).  The field of view on my phone is about 6x10mm,with a sub-mm depth of focus and a working distance short enough that the phone blocks quite a lot of light (the LED on my phone isn't in a helpful place). It's probably on the limit of what you can do on something meant for hand holding

Comment: @ChrisH : Yeah. Sounds good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that there is little you can do, but just get closser to your subject.

Try a loupe. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loupe Normally a smaller one has more "magnification".

Smartphones has normally a very wide angle lens, so a DIY solution to change that viewing angle is complicated.

Comment: I think the term you're looking for is "[loupe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loupe)"?

Comment: Tanks. That is it. Answer edited.